# Считывание файла через функцию

Tags: c++, файлы

Подскажите как написать функцию считывания строки с номера N до номера M, чтобы ее потом можно было потом использовать для считывания с M+1 до К. Я реализовал решение, но в нем требуется перейти в начало файла, потом через функцию GoToLine(M+1) перейти на M+1 строку, а потом с M+1 до K.

Хочу, чтобы можно было это функцию так использовать - GetMN(FILE,N,M);GetMN(FILE,M+1,K);

Реализовано сейчас - GetMN(FILE,N,M); FILE.CLEAR(); FILE.SEEKG(0); GoToLine(M+1); GetMN(FILE,M+1,K);

```
void GetMN(std::fstream& file,int n,int k){

..

}
```

Comment: Сохраняйте текущую стрку в дополнительной переменной (передавайте ее по указателю) в этой же функции

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void reader(ifstream & Y, int N, int M, int K)
{
    string t;
    while (!Y.eof())
    {
        for (int i = N; i < M; i++)
        {
            getline(Y, t);
        }
        for (int i = M; i < K; i++)
        {
            getline(Y, t);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream Q("namefile.txt");
    //int N = 2, M = 6, K = 9;  example
    reader(Q,N,M,K);
    Q.close();
}
```

Comment: если еще актуально